# Locate iCloud and UIDocument project on Github?

Tags: swift, icloud

Can anyone link me to a GitHub project (I can’t find any on the Apple dev site) which uses iCloud and UIDocument? Preferably similar to the iOS version of Pages.

I’m getting a lot of smaller errors/bugs in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Apple's [Lister](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Lister/Introduction/Intro.html) example.

Comment: I have been trying to get iCloud set up in a test application and downloaded the Lister Sample app you mention here but that seems to have the same issue I can't seem to overcome. When the application is running and you go to Settings/iCloud/iCloud Drive and turn it off, the application crashes with no error messages and sitting at the AppDelegate.